# How to turn a file into a list

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a text file with numbers into a list
the text file is

```
1.89
1.99
2.14 
2.51  
5.03  
3.81  
1.97 
2.31  
2.91  
3.97 
2.68 
2.44
```

Right now I only know how to read the file. How can i make this into a list?
afterwards how can I assign the list to another list?
for example

```
jan = 1.89
feb = 1.99
```

etc

Code from comments:

```
inFile = open('program9.txt', 'r') 
lineRead = inFile.readline() 
while lineRead != '': 
    words = lineRead.split() 
    annualRainfall = float(words[0]) 
    print(format(annualRainfall, '.2f')) 
    lineRead = inFile.readline() 
inFile.close()
```

Comment: entire file is supposed to be a list
these numbers are for a program that read the total rainfall for each of the 12 months into a list that i need to write

Comment: inFile = open('program9.txt', 'r')

lineRead = inFile.readline()       
    while lineRead != '':              
       words = lineRead.split()
       annualRainfall = float(words[0])
       print(format(annualRainfall, '.2f'))
       
       
       lineRead = inFile.readline()    
       
    
    inFile.close()

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is already an iterable of lines, so you don't have to do *anything* to make it into an iterable of lines.

If you want to make it specifically into a *list* of lines, you can do the same thing as with any other iterable: call [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#list) on it:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

But if you want to convert this into a list of floats, it doesn't matter what kind of iterable you start with, so you might as well just use the file as-is:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    floats = [float(line) for line in f]
```

(Note that [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) ignores trailing whitespace, so it doesn't matter whether you use a method that strips off the newlines or leaves them in place.)

---

From a comment:

> now i just need to find out how to assign the list to another list like jan = 1.89, feb = 1.99 and so on

If you know you have exactly 12 values (and it will be an error if you don't), you can write whichever of these looks nicer to you:

```
jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec = (float(line) for line in f)
jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec = map(float, f)
```

However, it's often a bad idea to have 12 separate variables like this. Without knowing how you're planning to use them, it's hard to say for sure (see [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) for some relevant background on making the decision yourself), but it might be better to have, say, a single dictionary, using the month names as keys:

```
floats = dict(zip('jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(),
                  map(float, f))
```

Or to just leave the values in a list, and use the month names as just symbolic names for indices into that list:

```
>>> jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec = range(12)
>>> print(floats[mar])
2.14
```

That might be even nicer with an [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum), or maybe a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Again, it really depends on how you plan to use the data after importing them.

Comment: Ah, float! This is the best solution :) I am deleting mine

Comment: is it possible to do without using "with open"?

Comment: with open creates an execution context which will ensure the file gets automatically closed when this indented block ends

Comment: this works great for my function!! thank you abarnert...
now i just need to find out how to assign the list to another list like 
jan = 1.89, 
feb = 1.99 and so on...

Comment: @spuriousarbiter: Sure, it's possible to do it without a `with` statement, but why would you want to?

Comment: @spuriousarbiter: For the second question, I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'll try to guess and answer.

Comment: this is my original question that i am trying to answer!!                 
   [Write a program that read the total rainfall for each of the 12 months into a list. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.]

Comment: i integrated your codes into mine and i've got my program going!

` with open('program9.txt') as inputs:
    floats = [float(line) for line in inputs]
jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec = range(12)
a = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oto', 'Nov', 'Dec']
for months in range(len(a)):
    print(a[months], floats[months]) `

Answer (score 2):

```
months = ('jan', 'feb', ...)

with open('filename', 'rb') as f:
  my_list = [float(x) for x in f]

res = dict(zip(months, my_list))
```

This will however work ONLY if there are the same number of lines than months!

Comment: Why would you read the whole file and call `splitlines` on it just to get something you can use as an iterable of lines, which the file already was?

Comment: No, you can't call `splitlines()` on a file object; that's a method on `str`. Just don't call it at all. (Also, while we're at it, why are you opening the file in binary mode?)